# Retrieve DataProperties and Sub Properties of Data Properties separately using OWL API

Tags: eclipse, api, owl, ontology

I am working with owl api 4.0 in eclipse. The ontotlogy is so designed that an individual has properties and every property has inturn sub property as shown in following figure:-
[image]

I want to retrieve the main properties i.e canCraw, canBreath, legs and then their sub properties separately. i used following code:-

```
OWLClass animalCl = datafactory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(myOntologyIRI + "Animal")); // Animal is the Class name
NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> animalIndl = reasoner.getInstances(animalCl, false);

for (OWLNamedIndividual animalNamedIndl : animalIndl.getFlattened())
{
 line1:    Set<OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom> animalPropAll= myOntology.getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms(animalNamedIndl);
 mainprop: for (OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom ax: animalPropAll) 
  { 
   System.out.println("the propery retrieved = " + ax.getProperty()) ;  // the sub properties are printed out here alongwith main properties

       line2: NodeSet<OWLDataProperty> properties = reasoner.getSubDataProperties((OWLDataProperty) ax.getProperty(), false);
     subprop: for (OWLDataProperty mysubproperty : properties.getFlattened())
      System.out.println("and the sub property is " + mysubproperty); // this is where i expect the sub properties of the properties
  }
}
```

the output of above mentioned code is:-

```
the property retrieved = <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#canCrawl> // this is fine                                                   
the property retrieved = <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#crawlWt>  // why is this sub property being printed here? (printing from mainprop for loop)  
and the sub property is <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#crawlWt>      // this is fine (printing from subprop for loop)
          .
          .
          .
 the property retrieved = <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#legs>        // this is fine                                                   
 the property retrieved = <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#legsWt>  // why is this sub property being printed here?  
 and the sub property is <http://localhost:3030/BiOnt.owl#legsWt>   // this is fine
```

What am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`reasoner.getSubDataProperties((OWLDataProperty) ax.getProperty(), false);`

The `false` parameter means subproperty at any level.
If you switch it to true, the reasoner will provide you with the direct subproperties only. If I understand your requirement correctly, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have amended the code. issue is not related to line 2 (which you have mentioned in your answer). The issue is line 1. the line 1 is generating not only properties, but sub properties of those properties. i.e getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms(animalNamedIndl) prints not only 3 properties of individual 'animalNamedIndl' but also 3 subproperties of those properties too as shown in protege snapshot in my question.

Comment: the documentation says getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms returned properties contained in ontology that have the specified individual as the subject of the axiom. By this definition, all properties and sub properties will be returned. my question is, if i only want to retrieve the main properties then how to do it?

Comment: In that case you will have to navigate the property hierarchy. Ask the reasoner for direct subproperties of TopDataProperty, then iterate over the results to get the next level of subproperties.